# What is the maximum size of ABI in real world contracts?

Tags: contract-development, events, abi

To monitor my contracts during development and test in a private blockchain I’ve written an event explorer that encodes beside other parameter the ABI in an URL parameter. The ABI will be compressed and hex encoded (like in the example link below).

Due to the fact that the length of URLs is limited depending on the used browser to about 2k the ABI can’t be endless long. I'd like to estimate, how many real world contracts I can handle with this technique. On Etherscan we can see many verified contracts, but not filter by size.

**Do you know a statistic of the size (ABI) of verified contracts in main network?** Some contract addresses of unusual large contracts would be good.

**Example URL:**

https://ethereum-event-scan-stg.cert4trust.de/?searchKey=&provider=https:%2F%2Fleopold-node3-rpc-stg.cert4trust.de&start=0&refresh=true&abi=eJzdmMtu2zAQRf%2BFa6%2BaogvvAmeRLgoUdR6LwChocWITkUmDQyoRAv97SdkS9XDlJHraS4mD4bnUkHOpp3fCxdZoJNOnxYRsaUyXIZDpMw0RJgQ11fDLaLrkIdcxmRIhRRo0ITre2lgSSIFamUBLRXaTd0JtULyRBrM82RxuOgZvwHJDGpSg4d0%2BF2VMAaJNLujGvfgbKKAuczZdGuKmOpHNYnGx8skiUMil8LkOAbtFFjLzYm6kyKmECIRuXx9HNPA1dctYA159y63VmuLap0rHc%2BpubcDMLajNennK%2FsBGRheqLKIhZxf73SL50oMyGgTS2MRVaZ7nNzXYBMWeHW2SqGvGxoTT0RYrH9RGhdVD%2BvPnPfKVoNooqCbzwuZp0GxNxWokZXhv2%2BxYCvFxzTWEHPU123AxmoIsYjUuzA7AgI1vsYDVrFTi5Kh9OArVnMK%2B2h8jNkoa3dR4PhsRaOfnemIvVtyZa0gqYEABFa9w0iokNwG43Yd1R55uuvbAV6Ad9dxSGSywn%2F6s9W6sCCZlmLvrOMOYw3KDuw%2BtVcTh9bOrVBD7UySTzw71WCPX2Ocf3z20n%2FYw0hPxPGcUanDL%2FuKoregB9z6xR2cA%2BjD%2BOmjnZOV4pLGd2KG9bc62JNb0v4uVWmqTg%2Bks91MPm1wU%2BuyIpalHukAt9G2VOOXODUc3Xm8PP5Tdy3MIyxrAAMa%2FCjGgg6%2BBOT8rrrL%2FkcPvji%2FRy5cRkH%2F8r1fzv1z4P5PbX90b0UmrWvwDsBVCJg%3D%3D&contract=0x9834FF49d61ac04Cd8Bf2E21a12F8aacc007A8E4

**Expected Page:**
[image]

Comment: In the real world, it cannot be larger than the number of atoms in the known universe, which is about 10^80. And more generally, this sounds like a question about URLs, not about Ethereum.

Comment: According EIP 170 (see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-170.md) the size of a contract's binary in Ethereum is limited to a maximum of 24576 bytes. So, there is a real world limit less than 10^80. The question is about the distribution of real contracts.

Comment: That's the bytecode size, not the ABI size!